# Multiplying DF row by coefficients

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I want to store the coefficients of a statsmodels.api model for future use (so I don't have to run the model every time). When I get a new dataframe for which I want to make a prediction on, I want to be able to multiply each row of the dataframe by the coefficients( i.e. model.params). I would then sum the results of each row*coefficients to get the prediction for that row. However, it does not seem to be working for me when I try:

```
preds = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    preds.append((model.params*row).sum())
```

Edit: example

df:

```
Height    Weight    Color
  6         5         3
  6         2         4
  9         1         9
  10        3         3
```

coefficients:

Height: -1.6403

Weight: 2.0435

Color: 300.4532

Comment: Can you prepare the question with some input data and expected output? [MCVE]

Comment: yes, I just did that for you harv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider doing something like:

```
df.dot(model.params)
```

This computes the dot product on each of the rows of the DataFrame.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! (and probably more efficient than a method I would have devised)

Comment: Thanks! that's a good reason to mark it as the correct answer :) @big11mac

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need:

```
coeff_dict = {
        'Height': -1.6403,
        'Weight': 2.0435,
        'Color': 300.4532
 }
df.assign(prediction=df.assign(**coeff_dict).mul(df).sum(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    Height  Weight Color  prediction
0       6       5      3    901.7353
1       6       2      4   1196.0580
2       9       1      9   2691.3596
3      10       3      3    891.0871
```